# How can I redirect all web requests to a specific subdomain on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a website that I only want to serve requests at:

```
abc.mywebsite.com
```

I want any requests to:

```
www.mywebsite.com
mywebsite.com
<anything that is not abc>.mywebsite.com
```

to be directed to `abc.mywebsite.com`, because I have a certificate specifically for that. How can I write my conf file to accomplish this?

Here is my conf file as it stands:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 adefault_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   443 default ssl;
    server_name abs.mywebsite.com;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/abc.mywebsite.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;


    root /home/mywebsite/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `default_server` block for both HTTP and HTTPS. That block will handle your redirect.

It will look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    return 301 https://abc.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

This blocks redirects any request to any virtual host to `abc.mywebsite.com` and original request URI. You might want to strip the `request_uri`, because quite often there is no matching page.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ... ssl_certificates here ...

    return 301 https://abc.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This block redirects any request arriving at any virtual host at port 443 to `abc.example.com` and original URI. With TLS you need to have valid certificates for the domains you are redirecting, and you need to set them up properly in order this to fully work.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name abc.example.com;

    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/abc.mywebsite.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    root /home/mywebsite/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
}
```

This is the actual block for the `abc.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to each server block:

```
if ($host !~* ^abc\.mywebsite\.com$ ) {
    return 301 https://abc.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

And it works exactly like I want it to. I know some people don't like `if` statements. Well then why are they there? Works perfectly.